# How to restrict Profile to see the Cases based on record type in salesforce?

Tags: listview, salesforce, recordtype

I have 2 Profiles, `Manager` and `Agent`, `Manager` should be only able to see all cases where `recordtype=AAA` and Agent should be able to see where all Cases where `recordtype=BBB`. I have `Sub-Status = Draft`, all those `Sub-Status=Draft` should not be visible to both profiles.

How we can restrict this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via sharing settings and rules as these works on data visibility. Profiles can only give you access to object/fields and what type of actions you can do (Create Read Update Delete, View All, Modify All).